# css on same named form fields

Tags: html, css, forms

so I have multiple forms on a page (don't know how many, created by php in an array).  Each one is simple and contains a number of fields, each with a `name='fieldname'`.

Now in the CSS I have:

```css
form.sidemenu input[name=fieldname] { width: 40px; }
```

This works fine on the first instance of the form, but it doesn't have any effect on the appropriate fields in the rest of the forms.  I've now tried replacing this with specific classes in each input field (`input name='fieldname' class='fieldname'`....) and replaced `form.sidemenu input.fieldname { width: 40px; }` and still no luck with the subsequent ones, although the first form works fine.

This is on Chrome Canary and Safari on OSX Lion, both behaving the same.

I know it's not something completely dumb (like missing out the class on the form) as (1) this is a form generated by a php loop so they're all the same, and (2) the CSS works perfectly on the first instance of the form, but not at all on the subsequent ones...

Comment: please share your markup

Comment: Wild guess: the other forms don’t have `class=sidemenu`.

Comment: you'd have to put up your code for anyone of us to help.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="fieldname" id="name"/>
    <input type="text" class="fieldname" id="and_So_on"/>
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
.fieldname {
     width: 40px;
}
```

**OR** You could try putting form in a `DIV` like:
CSS:

```css
div.sidemenu input {
     width: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidemenu">
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="fieldname" id="name"/>
        <input type="text" class="fieldname" id="and_So_on"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Is this how it looks like? Now it will apply to all of the elements with `class="fieldname"` on the entire page. But it is worth a try just for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Nikola. I'm still learning Stackoverflow :)